# htaccess redirect with query string on iis

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting

I have recently changed hosting from linux to windows

Now a redirection like

```
RewriteRule ^exit?([.]*)$ /exit.php?$1 [L]
```

does not work.

I mean it does not add query string as match $1 to exit.php

So anything like

```
exit?qs=hjdskgfh
```

end up like

```
exit.php?
```

with no qs added

server uses Helocin ISAPI_Rewrite 3 module

how to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the rule to

RewriteRule ^exit?([.]*)$ /exit.php\?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

And this works now